# Why will my function not loop as expected?

Tags: loops, substring

Below is a code sample for a function that removes similar adjacent characters in a string. For a given arguement like **remove_adjacent("azyyzb")**, the expected output should be **ab**, since it should first remove adjacent characters **yy** to get substring **azzb**. It should then remove adjacent characters **zz** in the substring, to finally get substring **ab**. However, my function only handles the first adjacent characters, and fails to handle the second part. It could be an indication that it is not looping as expected. Could someone point out what the problem might be?

```
public static void remove_adjacent(String str1)
{

  int i = 0;
  do
  {
    int j = i + 1;
    if (str1.charAt(i) == str1.charAt(j))
      str1 = str1.substring(0, i) + str1.substring(j + 1, str1.length());
    i++;
  }
  while (i < str1.length() - 1);

  System.out.println(str1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `i` is already pointing at index `2` when you remove `yy`. But your first `z` is at index `1`, which won't be checked anymore.

When you remove a part of the string, you will need to go one position backwards in your string to check, if a new pair of equal characters was created. And you must only step forward, if nothing was removed in the current iteration.

```
public static void remove_adjacent(String str1)
{

  int i = 0;
  do
  {
    int j = i + 1;
    if (str1.charAt(i) == str1.charAt(j)) {
      str1 = str1.substring(0, i) + str1.substring(j + 1, str1.length());
      if (i > 0) i--;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  while (i < str1.length() - 1);

  System.out.println(str1);
}
```